# Counting the number of specific values in a column with awk

Tags: awk, text-parsing

I have data (`data.csv`):

```
"1",5.1,"s"
"2",3.3,"s"
"3",2.7,"c"
```

and I want to count the number of line whose 3rd element is "s" or "c" with AWK (`count.awk`):

```
BEGIN{FS=","; s_count=0; c_count=0}
($3=="s"){s_count++}
($3=="c"){c_count++}
END{print s_count; print c_count}
```

then

```
$awk -f count.awk data.csv
```

but this does not work. Its output is:

```
0
0
```

this is not I expected. Why?

```
$ awk -V
GNU Awk 4.1.0, API: 1.0 (GNU MPFR 3.1.2, GNU MP 5.1.2)
```

Note: I use Awk on cygwin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your target **field has embedded double quotes**, so you **need to match them too**, by including them - `\`-escaped - in the string to match against:

```
awk '
  BEGIN{FS=","; s_count=0; c_count=0}
  ($3=="\"s\"") {s_count++}
  ($3=="\"c\"") {c_count++}
  END{ print s_count; print c_count }
  ' data.csv
```

---

As an aside, you can simplify your `awk` program somewhat:

- the parentheses are not needed (have not verified on `cygwin`, but given that it's `awk` interpreting the string, I wouldn't expect that to matter)
- you don't strictly need to initialize your output variables, because `awk` defaults uninitialized variables to `0` in numerical contexts.

```bsh
BEGIN{FS=","}
$3 == "\"s\"" {s_count++}
$3 == "\"c\"" {c_count++}
END{ print s_count; print c_count }
```

Comment: Actually, I tried $3==\"s\", but this resulted in syntax error
but I couldn't come up with $3 == "\"s\"" .
Thank you.

Comment: @keisuke: My pleasure; glad it worked for you. The syntax error is to be expected, because you still need to enclose the overall string in unescaped `"` chars. to tell `awk` that what is enclosed is a _string_.

Answer (score 1):

This is a job for an array.  Here is an `awk` command:

```
awk -F, '{gsub(/\"/,"",$3);a[$3]++} END {for (i in a) print i,a[i]}' file
c 1
s 2
```

It counts the number of `c` and `s` occurrences. Also counts other letters if they exist.